# Issues initializing repository in existing directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git

I have created a Rails app and now was trying to initialize repository in current project folder by following these guidelines - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

However, on executing command

```
git init
```

I'm getting following error -

```
fatal: bad config value for 'core.safecrlf' in /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.gitconfig
```

Comment: What does your .gitconfig file contain, especially for `core.autocrlf`?

Comment: Typed `vim ~/.gitconfig` and it shows `input` as value for it

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I meant `core.safecrlf`.

Comment: Same thing for that too. `[core]    
        autocrlf = input
        safecrlf = input
[credential]
        helper = osxkeychain`

Comment: Try `safecrlf = true` or `false`, I don't think that `input` is valid.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. That solved my issue. Do you want to put this as an answer so that I can mark it as such.

Comment: Will do, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the chat we had in the comments, it seems like your `core.safecrlf` was set to `input`, which doesn't appear to be a valid option for that setting.

Valid values for the The `safecrlf` setting include `true`, `false`, and `warn` (unless I've missed any).

From the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> core.safecrlf - If **true**, makes git check if converting CRLF is
>   reversible when end-of-line conversion is active. Git will verify if a
>   command modifies a file in the work tree either directly or
>   indirectly. For example, committing a file followed by checking out
>   the same file should yield the original file in the work tree. If this
>   is not the case for the current setting of core.autocrlf, git will
>   reject the file. The variable can be set to "**warn**", in which case git
>   will only warn about an irreversible conversion but continue the
>   operation.

Hope that helps.